# Auto generate id

Tags: java

I'm trying to auto generate an id for customers, 
and all i get is 0 every time.

Pretty sure the problem is in `public void regCustomer()`.

```
public class User {
private String firstName, gender, age;
String surename;
private int customerID;
private static int idCounter = 1000;
User next;

public User(String fN, String sn, String g, String a) {
    firstName = fN;
    surename = sn;
    gender = g;
    age = a;
    //customerID = cID;
    next = null;
}

public void setCustomerID() {
    customerID = idCounter++;
}

public int getCustomerID() {
    return customerID;
}

public String toString() {
    return customerID + "\t" + surename + "\t" + firstName + "\t" + age
            + "\t" + gender;

}
```

}

In the `Window` class

```
public void regCustomer() {


    //int customerID = 0;//= Integer.parseInt(customerIDField.getText());
    String firstName = firstNameField.getText();
    String surename = surenameField.getText();
    String gender = genderField.getText();
    String age = ageField.getText();

    if (!firstName.equals("") && !surename.equals("") && !gender.equals("")&& !age.equals("")) {
        userA.regCustomer(new User(firstName, surename, gender,age));
        User u = new User(firstName, surename, gender,age);
        u.getCustomerID();
        customerIDField.setText("");
        firstNameField.setText("");
        surenameField.setText("");
        ageField.setText("");
        genderField.setText("");
        firstNameField.requestFocus();
    } else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Alle felt må fylles inn");
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a `setCustomerID()` method that you never call. So presumably the `int` stays at its default value of 0.

Comment: The problem is that every time the program register a new customer it get customer id: 0. i want it to start on 1000++

Answer (score 4):

You never set the ID and that is why it is zero.

You can use a `private static final AtomicInteger` to generate your id sequence; simply read from it in your constructor:

```
private static AtomicInteger ID_GENERATOR = new AtomicInteger(1000);

public User(String fN, String sn, String g, String a) {
    customerID = ID_GENERATOR.getAndIncrement();
    //rest of constructor
}
```

You should use an `AtmoicInteger` as this is thread safe and the `getAndIncrement` method is atomic. There are not such guarantees for an `int`.

The question that needs to answered is whether these items are persisted in any way, and if so what happens then - id generation will always start from 1000 using this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Move `customerID = idCounter++;` to the constructor.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that an `AtmoicInteger` should be used as an `int++` isn't guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Indeed it is, but somehow I think OP has a long way to go before he starts thinking about multi-threading. When I was at that phase, answers like yours (while correct) were not very helpful because they relied on logic that I couldn't wrap my head around.

Comment: I did this. Only problem now is that the customers get different ID every time i reopen the program..

Comment: @user2248471 If you need to have persistent data - i.e. if you want customer ID's, balances etc. to persist when you close and re-open the program, you'll have to serialize ("save") your data to a file before closing it each time and deserialize("open") the file when you open it. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html